# Metamask randomly sending funds from one account to a saved address

Tags: metamask, etherscan

My Metamask just sent 1 ETH for absolutely no reason of my own, to another one of my saved wallet addresses in my address book. this makes absolutely no sense as I did not initiate the transaction myself. The log shows the transaction was created today and I can't for the life of me explain how this has happened.

The address it sent it to was my Gate.io wallet which I have not used for over a month. The wallet it sent it from is only two weeks old.
The nonce of the transaction sent is 90, and my current nonce is 99, which is perfectly normal.
Is there any reasonable explanation for this? if i was hacked why wouldn't they just empty the entire wallet which had considerably more than 1 ETH in it, and why would they send it to one of my own wallets?

The only thing i can think of is a bug in metamask..

if anyone has any ideas I'd really appreciate it, currently having a very big panic.

[image]

Comment: I understand the panic, but I don't think metamask even has the capability to send transactions on it own - otherwise it would be a huge security issue. Unfortunately I'm not sure what I could tell you...

Comment: anyway, I suggest you transfer all assets out of that wallet. to a hardware wallet, is available

Comment: is it possible this is a transaction thats been pending on my system for the last month? thank you btw, appreciate you getting back to me

Comment: Not in your system, but in the mempool - in theory, possibly. But if you have made successful transactions after that from the account, then that's not possible

Answer (score 0):

I'm an engineer on the MetaMask team. If you still have MetaMask installed, we would like to investigate this further.

Would you be able to submit state logs in a support ticket?

This explains how to download state logs: https://metamask.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360015290092-How-to-download-state-logs

Then you can click the "Contact MetaMask Support" link within MetaMask:

[image]

And click "Open a ticket" on the page that link takes you to:

[image]

Thank-you